# Using vstest.console.exe, how do I get the fully qualified names of all the test methods of an assembly?

Tags: vstest.console.exe

The /ListTests option only outputs the methods name without their class and namespaces, this doesn't make any sense! And the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/vstest-console-options?view=vs-2017) doesn't seem to provide any additional tools to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently [someones else](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/1732) has figured it out by looking at the source code. There is an undocumented switch that allows do to this, but it has to output to a file, because it's "internal use only" (sigh).

So anyway I got it working with this command:

```
vstest.console.exe bin\x64\Release\DummyProjectTests.dll /ListFullyQualifiedTests /ListTestsTargetPath:tests.txt
```

And indeed the content is what you would expect:

> SuccessfulTests.FibonacciTests.GoodTest_1
>   SuccessfulTests.FibonacciTests.GoodTest_2
>   SuccessfulTests.FibonacciTests.GoodTest_3
>   SuccessfulTests.FibonacciTests.DataRowGoodTest

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks for finding this!